# What does ssis use to upload to firebird

Tags: c#, csv, ssis, oledb, firebird

I want to write an application to upload a CSV file to a firebird database, however, I can’t find anything that can match the speed of ssis. 
I have a csv file with 750,000 records, I can’t find any bulk upload for firebird so upload row by row via odbc and commit every 1000 rows. This takes about 18 minutes. However, if I create a package in SSIS using the odbc driver it uploads in 2.5 minutes. Is it possible to use the same underlying tools in a standard c# application? If so does anyone know what it is or how I can find out?

Also if I replicate the same SSIS package using a trial of the oledb driver (which I thought should be faster than the odbc driver) it then takes 30 minutes, any ideas about this? I have used batch and row by row but there seems to be no difference.

Comment: Please show your code that uses ODBC and takes 18 minutes.

Comment: why use ODBC - rather old standard - with C#, when you have native .Net Provider http://firebirdsql.org and OLE DB http://ibprovider.com ? Also, if you need raw speed, then perhaps drop C# and use native C++ with IB++ library? Also look into http://fbexport.sourceforge.net/ sources, how fast can it do CSV import and maybe some treaks in their source code

Comment: @MarkRotteveel you think he forgets to prepare and uses value injection instead? https://www.bobby-tables.com/ Maybe... However, once i used simple table stuffing with Delphi and rather light-weight UIB library. Guess what? Pushing a script of thousands of INSERT statement with literals worked actually faster than "proper" preparing and using parameters. Maybe it would be different on the network, but locally feeding script turned faster.

Comment: thanks for the replies and sorry for the delay (i have been away). i am looking to automate the task using ssis and odbc is the only free option i can see, the ibprovider oledb option requires a license that i cannot obtain, the free version (v3) does not allow for pulling the schema from the database and so wont work for what i need to do. As a last resort i was looking to create a C# application to automate it, but couldn't match the speed of ssis. in the odbc code for inserts there was no need to use a script component, but for updates i did use a script component and used parameters